# Calculate rotation angle for anchor point

Tags: ios, calayer, cgaffinetransform

I got stuck with a problem where I need to reposition views to predefined locations.

All views have a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and a `UIRotationGestureRecognizer` and are positioned/rotated inside the controllers view. Upon a certain event the views should move to a new position with a new rotation angle.

Everything works fine but a soon as one of the gesture recognizer was active and thus the `anchorPoint` has changed repositioning/rotation fails.

Here is my method I try to use to take the shift in the `anchorPoint` into account.

```c
  - (CGPoint)centerPointWithInVisibleAreaForPoint:(CGPoint)point  
 {
    CGPoint anchorP = self.layer.anchorPoint;
      anchorP.x    -= 0.5;
      anchorP.y    -= 0.5;

    CGRect rect = self.bounds;

    CGFloat widthDelta  = CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds)  * anchorP.x;
    CGFloat heightDelta = CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds) * anchorP.y;

    CGPoint newCenter = CGPointMake(point.x + widthDelta, point.y + heightDelta);

    return newCenter;
}
```

The controller asks for the corrected center point and sets the center value of the view. Afterwards the rotation transform is set using `CGAffineTransformConcat(view.transform, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(differenceAngle))`.

I think the problem is caused by the fact that the predefined target angle is based on a rotation around the center which is obviously different when rotated around a different `anchorPoint`, but I don't know how to compensate for that.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found (and it is after all the most easiest one) is to reset the anchorPoint to 0.5/0.5 and correct the position accordingly.

```c
- (void)resetAnchorPoint
{
   if (!CGPointEqualToPoint(self.layer.anchorPoint, CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5))) {

    CGFloat width = CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds);
    CGFloat height = CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds);

    CGPoint newPoint = CGPointMake(width * 0.5, height * 0.5);
    CGPoint oldPoint = CGPointMake(width * self.layer.anchorPoint.x, height * self.layer.anchorPoint.y);

    newPoint = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(newPoint, self.transform);
    oldPoint = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(oldPoint, self.transform);

    CGPoint position = self.layer.position;
    position.x += (newPoint.x - oldPoint.x);
    position.y += (newPoint.y - oldPoint.y);

    [CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];
    self.layer.position    = position;
    self.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
    [CATransaction setDisableActions:NO];
  }
}
```